# compile irssi on iOS (Apple TV)

Tags: ios, configure

I'm trying to compile the latest release of irssi for execution on an appleTV 2 (ios) irssi already exists in the repos but it's an older version that wasn't build with perl support. I've got an application compiled on the device, a simple HelloWorld from http://imho.nu/Home/start-your-frappliance/appletv-mm-example/.

when I try to configure anything else prior to compiling, it fails with the error:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/download/irssi/irssi-0.8.15'
```

config.log reads:

```
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5555)
configure:3477: $? = 0
configure:3466: gcc -V >&5
gcc: '-V' option must have argument
configure:3477: $? = 1
configure:3466: gcc -qversion >&5
gcc: no input files
configure:3477: $? = 1
configure:3497: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3519: gcc    conftest.c  >&5
ld: library not found for -lSystem
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3523: $? = 1
configure:3561: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "irssi"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "irssi"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.8.15"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "irssi 0.8.15"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3566: error: in `/private/var/download/irssi/irssi-0.8.15':
configure:3570: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Can anyone shed some light on to what the issue may be? it seems that the script passes gcc '-V' instead of '-v' which may mess things up?

Answer (score 0):

Glad you found my imho.nu pages. I just jump in by testing the simple method. `apt-get install irssi`. This installed irssi 0.8.12 (20071006 0939) direct from cydia.

I installed :

```
wget http://apt.saurik.com/debs/libgcc_4.2-20080410-1-6_iphoneos-arm.deb
dpkg -i libgcc_4.2-20080410-1-6_iphoneos-arm.deb
apt-get install iphone-gcc ldid make
```

When I type `gcc -v` (not `-V`) it will give me :

```
AppleTV:/usr/bin root# gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: arm-apple-darwin9
Configured with: ../llvm-gcc-4.2/configure --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --host=arm-apple-darwin9 --enable-static=no --enable-shared=yes --prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var/cache/iphone-gcc --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --enable-wchar_t=no --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.0.0
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5555)
AppleTV:/usr/bin root#
```

See : http://imho.nu/iMHo/scripting-with-irssi/

Comment: in any case, your write up for imho.nu is good, but i dont think the perl module is loaded in that version of irssi. does your /LOAD output  include perl? mine doesn't. Also that version is 08.12 latest is 08.15

Comment: Also please add contact info or open comments on imho.nu